# bundle install error with conftest.c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.3

Currently failing to bundle and I can't quite pinpoint how to solve the issue.

```
╰─ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p598 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

It fails on a specific gem and won't bundle the gemfile in my repo

```
╰─ gem install eventmachine
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160317-25567-1hfkhwn.rb extconf.rb
-----
Using OpenSSL from pkg-config -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d/include && -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d/lib && -lssl -lcrypto
-----
checking for main() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
CXXFLAGS=$(cxxflags) -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result -Wno-address
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling conftest.c
conftest.c:3:21: fatal error: utility: No such file or directory
   #include <utility>
```

The issue is I'm not really sure where to look and google hasn't yielded anything helpful.

#### minor edit

I've tried:

```
brew unlink openssl
brew link openssl --force
```

but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this now doing:

```
rvm uninstall ruby-1.9.3-p545
```

(and the other rubies)

and then reinstalled using rvm. And it works!